# Register javascript inside User Control using C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, user-controls, scriptmanager

I want to call javascript function from User Control using C#. For that i am trying to use

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "alertbox", "javascript:ShowPopup('Select a row to rate');", true);
```

but it is not working for me. This works fine on the page. Can some one help me out how can i call javascript function at runtime using C#.

Thanks,

Comment: _What_ exactly isn't working? Is the script not there? Are there errors?

Comment: no there are no errors It just simply dont call javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is taken from working code, showing script being registered to fire from an asynchronous postback in an `UpdatePanel`.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript( this.upnl, this.upnl.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert('test');", true );
```

If your code is not executed from inside an `UpdatePanel`, it still should not be `typeof(string)`; you should use the type of some container (typically the control itself).

> **Type:** The type of the client script block. This parameter is
>   usually specified by using the typeof
>   operator (C#) or the GetType operator
>   (Visual Basic) to retrieve the **type of
>   the control** that is registering the
>   script.

Answer (score 5):

Try this.GetType() instead of typeof(string):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alertbox", "ShowPopup('Select a row to rate');", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if this is the best way to do it but for my user controls that use javascript i have a public string property on the user control and register it in the page.

// sudo code

eg.
UserControl

```
    {

   public bool CustomBool
   { 
     get
     {
       //logic 
       return value;
     }
    }

    public string Javascript
    {
        get { return "javascript...."; }
    }
  }
```

in page

```
{

    page load()
    {
         if (Usercontrol.CustomBool)
         {
               ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "alertbox", UserControl.Javascript, true);
         }
    }
}
```

The downside for this is you have to remember to register the scripts on the page. it does work though

Comment: yes, that did the trick but i am calling this alert on specific if else condition so for that i am checking using public bool property so there more work around need to set it false once i show alert :)

Comment: I have amended slighly to use a bool in the user control

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the "javascript:" in the script string:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "alertbox",  "ShowPopup('Select a row to rate');", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I find that the string given is embedded literally, so it's necessary to enclose it in a suitabie `<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>` and `</script>`

Comment: last bool parameter ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript() takes so that to enclose string with <script></script> tags